# hadoop native library @RHEL 7

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I am trying to get the hadoop native library support for snappy, and hence went down the path of compiling the source code  for hadoop-2.7.3, and OS version is RHEL 7.And during the build process, encountered errors below,  I know the problem is with c,c++,protobuf etc from the error logs, the error log is attached as well.Please advise.

```
the maven build fails at 
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  0.791 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [  0.696 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.022 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SUCCESS [  1.509 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SUCCESS [  2.138 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client ................... FAILURE [  2.475 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-RBF ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 22.401 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-27T13:25:12-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 94M/427M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs-native-client: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target" executable="make">... @ 9:132 in /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/antrun/build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs-native-client: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 2
around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target" executable="make">... @ 9:132 in /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/antrun/build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        a
```

**CMakeerror.log**

```
Determining if the pthread_create exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_38970/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc     -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_38970
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc       CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTC_38970 -rdynamic
CMakeFiles/cmTC_38970.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o: In function `main':
CheckSymbolExists.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_38970] Error 1
gmake: *** [cmTC_38970/fast] Error 2

File /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef pthread_create
  return ((int*)(&pthread_create))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}

Determining if the function pthread_create exists in the pthreads failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_f697c/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o   -c /usr/local/share/cmake-3.4/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.c
Linking C executable cmTC_f697c
"~/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log" 519L, 41169C
Linking C executable cmTC_f697c
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -DCHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=pthread_create    CMakeFiles/cmTC_f697c.dir/CheckFunctionExists.c.o  -o cmTC_f697c -rdynamic -lpthreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthreads
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_f697c] Error 1
gmake: *** [cmTC_f697c/fast] Error 2


Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test PROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_ba8c9/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++     -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DPROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE   -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/src.cxx.o -c /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTC_ba8c9
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DPROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE    CMakeFiles/cmTC_ba8c9.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_ba8c9 -rdynamic /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so /usr/lib/libprotoc.so
/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake[1]: *** [cmTC_ba8c9] Error 1
gmake: *** [cmTC_ba8c9/fast] Error 2

Source file was:
#include <google/protobuf/io/printer.h>
    #include <string>
    int main(void) {
      ::google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream *out = NULL;
      ::google::protobuf::io::Printer printer(out, '$');
      printer.PrintRaw(std::string("test"));
      return 0;
    }
Performing C++ SOURCE FILE Test PROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTC_3f00e/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3f00e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3f00e.dir/build

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/gmake" "cmTryCompileExec2395487968/fast"
/usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DPROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE   -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/src.cxx.o -c /root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec2395487968
/usr/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DPROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2395487968.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2395487968 -rdynamic -lprotobuf -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotoc.so when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotoc.a when searching for -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotoc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec2395487968] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hadoop-source/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs-native-client/target/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [cmTryCompileExec2395487968/fast] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you installed your kernel's headers? (`sudo yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`). `<pthread.h>` headers do not exist, and unless you're trying to compile hadoop for some embedded version of linux which does not support threads, you should be able to simply install the header files for pthread.

Comment: thanks sturcotte06,looks like the pthread errors are gone,  still get errors like /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/u 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotoc

Comment: You now need to install protobuf.

Comment: I have it installed already, looks like some path issue, does this mean protobuf is installed ?, root@10-119-xx-xx:/root # protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0

Comment: This is a rule if you're gonna compile native libraries: if you install a lib `x` you should always install `x-devel` as well. Some naming exceptions might apply (might be `y-headers` for some packages).

Comment: Also, there's two  environment variables called `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_INCLUDE_PATH`. They control where shared libraries and which header files respectively, are searched for.

Comment: not sure what to set those env variables with, please advice.Mean while I did some digging, and here is the command leading to those problems  
 /usr/bin/c++    -g -O2 -Wall -pthread -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -m32 -DPROTOC_IS_COMPATIBLE   CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec198463998.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTryCompileExec198463998 -rdynamic -lprotobuf -lprotoc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libprotobuf.a when searching for -lprotobuf
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lprotobuf